Multiple Shortest Path with node capacities
I am solving a multiple shortest path problem that has a characteristic I can't seem to find in the literature: each node in the network is labeled with the amount of outgoing arcs it can support (i.e., a node capacity).
I've been able to find previous work on minimizing the overlap of paths in a multi-agent/disaster recovery context, but nothing that constrains specific areas of the network to only allow some number of segments through them.
I know this is likely just a vehicle routing problem (VRP) / m-TSP variant with an additional constraint on the outbound arcs from a given node, but I was just wondering if anyone is aware of specific literature that formalizes this variant because I'd like to be able to cite it/reference it in my work.

Two clarifications: does this mean that some nodes have more outbound arcs than can be used per the node capacity; and if two shortest paths both include the arc (i, j), does that count as 2 (because the arc is used twice) or 1 (because it is one arc) when checking the node capacity limit?

Yes - for example, a node may have 10 outbound arcs but only up to 5 can be used in a solution. When checking the node capacity limit, only different arcs are counted. If only one arc is used, even by a bunch of different paths, it only counts as 1 towards the capacity limit. Thanks for responding!

As far as modeling goes, m-TSP has a nice compact formulation where variable x(i,j) = 1 if an arc is used (by any traveler) and 0 if not (the specific assignments can then be inferred by the solution). This encoding would be perfect for expressing my constraint.

There's an implicit tradeoff in path lengths caused by the arc limits (some paths being longer than minimal in order that others can use arcs that reduce their lengths). If it makes sense in your context to minimize the sum (or perhaps weighted sum) of the path lengths, you could model it as a variant of a multicommodity flow problem where each commodity corresponds to a different path, unit flow cost is 1 on every arc, supply = demand = 1 on each path and the capacity of arc $(i,j)$ is $Mx_{ij}$ where $M$ is the number of paths to compute and binary variable $x_{ij}=1$ if arc $(i,j)$ is in use and zero if not. Enforcing the arc limits is done using the $x$ variables. Sorry, I don't have a reference for this.

Yep, this is similar to how I've been tackling it... thank you for your response!
